# How to make a generic call to `ffi_closure`

Tags: c, closures, ffi

I want to call FFI closures (assuming that the user knows the return and argument types) from an array using a generic function like:

```
void *call(char *name, ...);
```

However, to call one I need to provide a list of arguments. For example, a closure defined in C like:

```
void func(ffi_cif *cif, void *ret, void *args[], void *stream) {
  printf("%d, %f, %c\n", *(int *)args[0], *(float*)args[1], *(char *)args[2]);
  *(ffi_arg *)ret = *(int *)args[0];
}

typedef int (*func_t)(int a, float b, char c);
```

Are called like this:

```
((func_t)bound_func)(5, 1.7f, 'x'); // bound_func is returned by ffi_closure_alloc
```

What is the recommended way to call the FFI closure with a variable return type and arguments generically?